# jQuery - combination of ".on" and ".each" on dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, each

I am dynamically adding new elements and these elements looks like this:

```
<div id="cars">
  <input type="text" name="car_added[]" class="car" />
  <input type="text" name="car_added[]" class="car" />
  <input type="text" name="car_added[]" class="car" />
  <input type="text" name="car_added[]" class="car" />
  <input type="text" name="car_added[]" class="car" />
</div>
```

If these elements would be static, I could add a handler on them easily with this code:

```
$(".car").each(function(){$(this).datetimepicker();})
```

and after clicking in the input, the date-time widget will display.

But how to do this for dynamically added elements? I've tried the following approach, but it doesn't work:

```
$('#cars').on('click', '.car', function() {
    $(this).datetimepicker();
});
```

How to implement into this snippet the `.each` part?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7bJ/98/

Comment: Yes - I click on "Add a new car" and then there will be displayed an input. After clicking into the input, I'd like to display the `datepicker` widget.

Comment: there is no need to have each part in the second sampel

Answer (score 2):

Try this : You need not to iterate and then apply datepicker to element. Just call `datetimepicker()` as shown below

```
$('#cars .car').datetimepicker();
```

**EDIT** - to add datetimpicker on dynamically generated elements, attache it when you are adding dynamically generated elements.

For Example - I am adding elements on button click. I need to add datetimepicker at the same time. See below code and jsfiddle demo

```
$(function(){
    //add datetimepicker for existing elements
    $('#cars .car').datepicker();
    
    //add datetimepicker for dynamically added elements when adding it
    $('#clickMe').click(function(){
      var newElement = $('<input type="text" name="car_added[]" class="car" />');
      //add datepicker here
      newElement.datepicker();  
      $('#cars').append(newElement);
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/pw1gs4uk/4/)**

**NOTE**- OP has used `datetimepicker` but please make note I have used datepicker instead of datetimepicker.

Comment: But this approach doesn't work on newly added elements.

Comment: @user984621..try my answer

Comment: @user984621 pleae check my edit. Please make note I have used datepicker instead of datetimepicker